# Entity framework returns null for a row if the first column in that row is null

Tags: c#, entity-framework, null, left-join

I'm seeing a weird behavior in my Entity Framework model.  I've got a query that looks like this:

```
var rows = ( from alarm in context.Alarms
             join temp  in context.ListDetails on alarm.ListDetailId equals  temp.ListDetailId into entries from entry in entries.DefaultIfEmpty()
             join read  in context.Reads       on alarm.ReadId       equals  read.ReadId
             join plate in context.Images      on alarm.ReadId       equals plate.ReadId
             where alarm.IActive == 1 && ! alarm.TransmittedAlarm 
             where  read.IActive == 1 
             where plate.IActive == 1 && plate.ImageTypeId == 2
             select new { alarm, entry, read, plate } ).ToArray();
```

The query returns all columns in alphabetical order by column name.  It turns out that this column is NULL for a few rows in the result set.  When I expand the rows variable in the debugger, I see that the entire row is null!

EDIT:  Some clarification.

By "first column", I mean the first column of the first row, i.e., in "SELECT A, B, C FROM ...", I mean A. It just happens that the query that Entity Framework builds returns all of the columns in the joined result set in alphabetical order, and the first one alphabetically is nullable and is null for some rows.

The column in question is not a primary key; if it were a primary key, it couldn't be null.

When Entity Framework processes the rows of the returned data into objects, it's looking at the value of the first column in each row.  If that column is null, it's returning null for the row, instead of an object with the property that corresponds to that column set to null.

I don't believe this has anything to do specifically with a left outer join; it just happens that my query uses one.  I haven't done any testing to verify this, however, so it's just a supposition.

Has anybody seen this before?  Does anyone have a fix for this?

Tony

Comment: Do you need a left join?

Comment: In what place do you get the error?

Comment: Could you post the SQL query that the EF sends to the DB?

Comment: I've checked the SQL and it's correct.  I'm getting a LEFT OUTER JOIN on the ListDetails table, as I wanted, and I have all the rows I expect.  The only thing is those rows that have the first column set to NULL are NULL in the rows variable, but they have other columns that are not null.  These are rows in the middle of the result set.

Comment: Can't help you since you don't give the SQL query. It's unclear what the 'first column' is, what it's meaning is. Is it a PK? Is it a EF-synthesized column? Based on what you have told, I can only say that it should work.

Comment: @PavelGatilov: Please see my edit in the question.

Comment: Have you checked in code (e.g. by iterating the `rows`) that `rows` have null items? I've seen situations when the VS debugger showed that a variable was `null`, while the code executed without `NullReferenceException`s. I mean that the VS debugger was incorrect.

Comment: If it's not the case, then it looks like a bug. The only way you could get help with it is posting the SQL query the EF generates and **detailed** description of 'the first column'. Which table it belongs to, its type, is it nullable, does it have any referential constraints? And we need that info for both the DB schema and the EF mappings. Also, what version of the EF do you use (exact assembly versions of 'System.Data.Entity.dll' and 'EntityFramework.dll')?

Comment: Or try to create a simple repro project and share it on some code hosting site.

Comment: I'm thinking it's a bug, myself. My question was whether anyone else had seen it before. I don't have the time right now to put together a test project and database, as we are looking at code freeze next week.  But I'll try to put something together after our release date next month.

Answer (score 6):

I can confirm that I have exactly same trouble: when SQL query formed by EF has `null` in first column of result, it return null instead of entity. It means exactly following:

```
using (var dc = new MyDbContext())
{
    var q = dc.Lands; //Lands is DbSet<Land>
    q = q.Where(criteria); //this leads to SQL query returning null in first column, confirmed by profiler
    var t = q.Single(); //t is now null
}
```

If we take another criteria, which does not result in `null` in first column, `t` is normal non-`null` entity.

It seems to me that it is some kind of obscure behavior/bug in EF.

**Update**

After several hours of probing I've found following behavior. EF does return `null` for entites having `NULL` in first column of result (which breaks expected behavior), but it has several notions about what column to put first in the select list. So, after making my model precisely consistent with my database state (which means denoting all `NULLABLE` database columns and replacing `required` navigation properties with `optional`) - I am using Code First, so there're plenty of places to be explicit about **database** - I've managed to get it to work.

It means that you should check store-level definition of your model (depending on what paradigm you use, designer-based, or code-based, it would be different places) against your database.

Answer (score 1):

You use `DefaultIfEmpty` in your join. It means

> If there're no items in `entries` that match the join criterion (`alarm.ListDetailId equals  temp.ListDetailId`), I want you to put a single default value of type `ListDetail` (which is `null`) into `entries`.

In this case EF generates a `LEFT JOIN`. In fact, this code is the well-known way to generate a `LEFT JOIN` with Linq2Sql or EF.

The `LEFT JOIN` statement selects `NULL` values for all columns of the table if no row in the table matches the `JOIN` criterion. In fact, the only column that matters is the PK column of the entity. EF checks if the PK value is `NULL`, decides that no entity exists and puts `null` into `entries`. Then you get this `null` as the `entry` property value of the results.

Comment: I need the Left Outer join.  The problem isn't that the `entry` is `NULL`; the problem is that the first column in the `alarm` is `NULL`and the entire select `new { alarm, entry, read, plate }` is returned as `NULL`, not just the `entry`.