# DbContext.Database.SqlQuery returns some null objects

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

Using `Entity Framework 6`, the code below queries a table (really, a view) and returns some number of rows. The number of rows is correct, but many of the rows are null, i.e. some of the `Licenses` objects are null, as seen in the Visual Studio Watch window. I think what is happening is that if any column of a given row in the view contains a null, then the entire row is being set to null.
Any ideas on how to get all the correct data?

```
String query = "select * from dbo.v_Licenses where [Number] like '%ab%'";
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbRawSqlQuery<Licenses> dbRawSqlQuery = db.Database.SqlQuery<Licenses>(query);
Queryable<Licenses> licenses = dbRawSqlQuery.AsQueryable();
```

Comment: What do you mean a "row" is null?  You mean some of the `Licenses` objects are null?

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing out the ambiguity. Clarification added.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10212913/entity-framework-returns-null-for-a-row-if-the-first-column-in-that-row-is-null) it seems like EF (at least at one point) returned `null` objects if the first column of the result set was `null`.  So rather then selecting `*` you should explicitly name the columns and ensure that the PK (or some other column) is first.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion as well. I changed the code to explicitly specify the columns with the first column being an Id which is defined as `(int, not null)` thus guaranteeing that the first column cannot have a null value, which I can also verify by looking at the view in SQL Server Management Studio. Nonetheless, I am still getting the same null objects.

Comment: Reading the question you linked to ... the last answer (from Serg Rogovtsev) talks about `NULLABLE` columns. Some of the columns in my view are marked `not null` and some are marked `null`. Do I have to specify something in the C# code to distinguish these columns?

Comment: Did you build the `Licenses` using code first or database first?  If some of those columns (except strings) are nullable you may need to define them as a nullable type (e.g. `int?`).

Comment: Database first. As it happens, all columns except for the aforementioned `Id` are varchar. I am playing with `[Required]` and `[Column(Order=x)]` at the moment.

Comment: The fix for me is to specify `[Column(Order=0)]` for the `Id` column. I did this and also changed the `select` statement back to * instead of specifying the columns. With this I get no null objects.

Answer (score 6):

Be sure that License properties'name are identical with columns that are fetched from the select and property type are identical, too.

Like this:

```
Select CustomerId,Firstname from Customers

public class Customer
{
      public int CustomerId{get;set;}

      public string Firstname {get;set;}
}
```

and change System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbRawSqlQuery  to List

I used this approach a lot and it worked very nice for me.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have verified that the Property names and Column names are identical

Answer (score 5):

In my case it did not work because I did NOT have the fields as properties. Once I converted the fields to properties it worked just fine.

Comment: This was precisely my problem as well. I was getting the correct number of rows, but all of my fields were null. I switched to properties and all was well.