# Entity Framework not returning data if the result has one or more column which is null

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

When you have a query that returns results where one or more columns are null, the query result is also null even though other columns have data. This is slightly similar to this stack overflow question:
[Entity framework returns null for a row if the first column in that row is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10212913/entity-framework-returns-null-for-a-row-if-the-first-column-in-that-row-is-null)

However in my case  it's not the first column returned by the result. It's also not a primary key column. query is on a view.

```
using (var ctx = new databaseEntities())
{
    return  ctx.MyView.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Column3 == someIntegerValue);
}
```

Also unlike the Stackoverflow question I don't have any joins in the query as you can see above. The view itself has joins.

A direct SQL query with

```
WHERE Column3 = someIntegerValue
```

returns a full row. The Entity Framework query works when no columns are null. The view was added to the designer using "Update Model from Database..." and then Add tab.

No changes were made to the view in any partial class or in design. Removing the two columns that sometimes return null from the view and then adding to the `.edmx` fixes this issue. The source for these two columns are udfs. Entity Framework version is 6.4.4

Answer (score -2):

You have to bind your nullable columnName in Include Property

You can try something like this,

```
using (var ctx = new databaseEntities())
{
 return  ctx.MyView.Include("ColumnName").FirstOrDefault(a => a.Column3 == someIntegerValue);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try this and report back

Comment: Running this with the ColumnName gives me the following error.(I've substituted the original names)
A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'Entity.MyView' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'ColumnName'.

Comment: Why would you use ColumnName. Instead you need to use what is your columnName which is nullable

Comment: I'm using the actual Column Name. i.e. "EmployeeNo" when testing. That's what I said in my reply : "(I've substituted the original names)" so that I don't give away our live database name. MyView is not the actual view name neither is ColumnName the actual Column. They're substituted to hide our actual database